# Google Glass Sample APKs

Tags: eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I can get the sample APK CompassActivity app to run on Glass but no luck with LevelActivity or StopWatchActivity? I am using Eclipse. Log below. Any suggestions?

```
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] ------------------------------
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] Android Launch!
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-07-29 17:02:18 - LevelActivity] Performing sync
[2013-07-29 17:02:28 - LevelActivity] Uploading LevelActivity.apk onto device '015DA7720F00D016'
[2013-07-29 17:02:28 - LevelActivity] Installing LevelActivity.apk...
[2013-07-29 17:02:29 - LevelActivity] Success!
[2013-07-29 17:02:29 - LevelActivity] /LevelActivity/bin/LevelActivity.apk installed on device
[2013-07-29 17:02:29 - LevelActivity] Done!
```

Comment: You can install via ADB, MyGlass app or compile the code and then say "OK, Google" and run them that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Run > Run Configurations`. Then, under `Launch Action`, change it from `Launch Default Activity` to `Launch:` and select the activity listed in the dropdown (e.g.`com.google.glass.samples.stopwatch.StopWatchActivity`). Hit Apply and try running the APK again.

The reason you have to do this is because the main activity for the sample code does not have `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in its `<intent-filter>`. Not having a launcher is intentional: there was a [pull request on one of the APK GitHub samples](https://github.com/googleglass/apk-compass-sample/pull/1) in the past and the response was:

> Thank you for the pull request; however, Glassware will not be launched in this fashion.

Comment: What if there aren't any activities listed in that dropdown?

Comment: As @Jay, there are no activities in the dropdown, any solutions ?

Comment: @AbdellahBenhammou I'm still getting used to launching things the Glass way, by starting a service that controls the activities' lifetimes. There's an interesting note in StartLevelActivity.java: "Having an activity that starts the service allows one to attach with the interactive debugger more predictably". I think that's a clue, but I don't have access to a device right now to try it on.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke hidden apps using Glass Launcher

If the App doesn't show up in the voice intentable menu, you can find it in glass-launcher. Glass Launcher stays a live card when your app is on.

1. Download the source  https://github.com/justindriggers/Glass-Launcher
2. Open Glass Launcher and scroll to your app.

Edit: you would have to linked GDK to compile.

Here is a compiled APK for Glass-Launcher for your convenience

https://github.com/jaredsburrows/OpenQuartz/blob/master/third-party/Launcher2.apk

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
Launch from the command line using this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.glass.samples.<sampleName>/.<MainActivityName>
```

so if you were launching the level it would be:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.glass.samples.level/.LevelActivity
```

or add this to the Android manifest for whichever project you are working on:

and install Launchy so you can launch the app whenever you please form Glass.

Answer (score 0):

use command -

```
adb install //location of .apk file

adb install -r build/apk/[app name]-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to get [ChromeADB](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeadb/fhdoijgfljahinnpbolfdimpcfoicmnm?hl=en) for the Chrome Browser to help!  It has many other capabilities that will be good for you.