# Cannot run camera demo code in eclipse.. No launcher found

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

> > I am a beginner at Glass/Android development. <<

When I try to run this camera demo, eclipse fails to find the launcher and aborts (which is expected since src is empty.. Here is what the console will throw:

> > [2014-06-13 20:16:08 - CameraDemoActivity] No Launcher activity found!
> >
> > [2014-06-13 20:16:08 - CameraDemoActivity] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

How can I fix this so it could run properly? I tried copying some of the java folder content into a package and calling the CameraDemoActivity.java from there but no use. Any idea how I could make this run properly without throwing a whole bunch of of errors?

Source code is here: https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo/tree/master/apidemo/camerademo

Help..

Thanks!

Hanna

Comment: Anyone figure this out? I am still at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginning Glass Developer. I've seen this before, and I believe it had something to do with two apks having the same name. Try deleting the app on the Glass and then run your code again. If no go, then try renaming the package.

I'm going to download your source and run it.

Sorry if that does not work, it was the first thought that popped in my head.

Peace,
TeckyTim

Comment: Hey @techyTim
It didn't work.. The app doesn't even download on Glass to delete it. 

let me know if you ran the code and it worked for you :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to AndroidManifest.xml to use unlisted voice commands:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

Please check :
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands

Then you should start the example with **"ok, glass" -> "start camera demo"**

Also, to run the application automatically from eclipse (not the Glassware way), you should set the Main activity in the project Launch configuration. In the project **Run As -> Run Configuration**. Select "Launch" and your main activity. In this case CameraDemoActivity.

Please check: 
[Google Glass Sample APKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952915/google-glass-sample-apks)

Comment: What line? I don't see the permission here : https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo/blob/master/apidemo/camerademo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sorry @fpanizza I must have added it to my code prior to posting the original message on Stackoverflow. But yeah I have it in my code..