# No Launcher activity found error on Eclipse - Google Glass XE 18.11

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I'm trying to run the sample code from the following

https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-waveform-sample

I know the sample is based on older version, but I'm trying to make it work with the current version.

I'm getting

```
> [2014-06-15 23:16:45 - WaveformActivity] Android Launch! [2014-06-15
> 23:16:45 - WaveformActivity] adb is running normally. [2014-06-15
> 23:16:45 - WaveformActivity] No Launcher activity found! [2014-06-15
> 23:16:45 - WaveformActivity] The launch will only sync the application
> package on the device! [2014-06-15 23:16:45 - WaveformActivity]
> Performing sync
```

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2013 Google Inc.

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.glass.sample.waveform"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.waveform.WaveformActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/trigger_show_me_a_demo" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question, basically I had to add the following line to the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a main activity, only a voice trigger.

So , to run your application you need to call it via **"ok, glass" -> "show me a demo"** voice trigger.

Also, if you want to run the application automatically from eclipse (not the Glassware way), you should set the a Main activity adding the intent filters:

```
 <activity  android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.waveform.WaveformActivity" >
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
      </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/trigger_show_me_a_demo" />
 </activity>
```

And set this main activity in the Project Launch configuration. In the project **Run As -> Run Configuration**. Select "Launch" and your main activity. In this case WaveformActivity.

Please check: 
[Google Glass Sample APKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952915/google-glass-sample-apks)

Answer (score -1):

you need to add in manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I thinks that if you are creating a glassware, you don't need this one. Just the voicetrigger.